# How to display Bitmap Image in Android

Tags: android, image, decoding

I am making an application in which i am getting an Mjpg Images from Live IP Camera in Android.

The problem is that since when i get the Image in the form of `ByteArray`. How can I display the `Image`?

I'm using the following code to display the image:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, start, a);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but i m getiing an exception

```
android.view.ViewRoot CallFromWrongThreadException
```

Please explain how to display the bytearray on android layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use runOnUiThread() to update views from other threads.

Answer (score 14):

```
ImageView tv1;
tv1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
InputStream si1 = asset.open("image/" + cat_arr1[i] + ".png");
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(si1);
tv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing some view related job always do it from GUI thread ie. `the thread that created the view hierarchy`  .

So use `Handlers` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The exception `CallFromWrongThreadException` means that you tried to update the UI from a thread that is not the UI thread and which is not allowed.

So your issue is not that your code to create the image is wrong, but that you are doing it at the wrong place.
If you e.g. are fetching the image in background in an `AsyncTask`, you need to `setImageBitMap()` in `postExecute()` and not in `doInBackground()`.

Without seeing more code, we can't help you more.

Answer (score 1):

```java
View mImg = findViewById(R.id.image_from_gallery);
((ImageView) mImg).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This worked for me.